# Prestashop 1.5.6.2 adding product in ajax stopped working

Tags: php, json, ajax, prestashop

my client is using prestashop 1.5.6.2 and products are added trough ajax-cart.js file that is sending correct POST to cart controller with id of product qty in params:

```
controller  cart
add 1
ajax    true
qty 1
id_product  92
token   4c30038914336909b4bab857c7ce7a1b
```

In response I get Status 200 and properly formated JSON that should contain all of added products and add it to cart right? Just the thing is, that JSON is empty no matter what product I try to add. It looks something like this:

```
products    []
discounts   []
shippingCost    0,00 zł
shippingCostFloat   0
wrappingCost    0,00 zł
nbTotalProducts 0
total   0,00 zł
productTotal    0,00 zł
hasError    false
```

I've look through the files, but not found any weird stuff in functions, there are no js errors or 500 code. Does anyone know anything how to fix that?

EDIT:

I've found out that guest_id always equals 0 no matter when loged or not.

Comment: My friend, you have to do some debug... Activate the debug mode in the `config/defines.inc.php` file, set to true the `_PS_MODE_DEV_` const. (obviously check the server configuration to display errors)

Comment: I did some manual checking and I'm sending correct values to function updateQty in Cart Controller line 259. But I don't know what happens next.